# Please Help with Syncing 2 Linear Actuators

Tags: actuator

I am a complete noob in regards to electrical wiring and scoured countless hours on the internet for help. I bought 2 DC12V 16inch Stroke Linear Actuators and connected it with a 20 AMP 12V - DC Motor Rocker Switch (dpdt?) and a 12V 6A AC DC power supply. The purpose was for a standing desk. It works really well but i noticed that it’s not synced (i am aware that it’s not possible to get it perfectly synced).

[image]

I read online that i am able to buy a DC speed controller to control the speed so I bought a 12V-40V 10A PWM DC Motor Speed Controller but it did not fix the issue. I wired the power supply directly into the speed controller P+/- and connected a wire from the dpdt that previously used to connect the power supply to the M+/- slot in the speed controller. Is it possible if I just buy an additional speed controller and connect a linear actuator to each controller in the M+/- slot and then plug the power supply where the linear actuators were previously plugged in the dpdt? For P +/-, i would introduce new wires for each controller and then crimp the wires together (- to -, + to +) and plug it to the dpdt to try and control each actuator separately. Do I need to use a relay? I'm confused as how to wire that together if necessary.

Sorry if this is very confusing as I don’t know the correct way to explain it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you using these for? why can't you just use one actuator? Are you able to servo it?

Comment: To raise a desk I would use a motor driving a chain drive and the chain drives gears on threaded bars - sorts the synchronisation...

Comment: You need some position feedback and a controller to exactly match the speeds of two actuators. If currently it's not terribly bad, just keep peace with it. If you have a speed controller, you can reduce the speed of the faster actuator by trial and error.

Comment: @Hearth It's for a standing desk. I figured it may be better to have two to share the load. Are you saying that i should buy a linear servo instead?

Comment: @SolarMike can you link me an example of a motor driving a chain drive?

Comment: @AbdullahBaig I do have a speed controller. Do i have to separate the 2 actuators? They're currently crimped together. I am confused as to how to reduce the speed of the faster actuator.

Comment: By "servo it" I just mean to add some feedback instead of just powering them directly.

Comment: You have to separate the motors. Run the slower one directly. Connect the faster one to the speed controller and try to give command to the speed controller to run a bit slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your application it would be advisable to use 2 such linear actuators with a dedicated controller and with position feedback for synchronized operation.

Since you have already purchased 2 actuators (without position feedback) and also a separate speed control unit, you would need to carry out the following:

1. Run both actuators at the same voltage for the same period and check the difference in travel.
2. Run the faster one through the speed control unit to reduce it's speed to match. Make a mark on this actuator to confirm that that's the one to be used with the speed control unit after final assembly.
3. Assemble, check for synchronized movement, and fine tune if necessary.
4. Always ensure that the desk is uniformly loaded.

Here's the schematic.

[image]

Comment: Would I connect the slower actuator in the M +/- slot in the speed controller? I'm confused on how the wiring in this process differs when I run the slower actuator directly into the speed controller and how to wire the faster actuator but this is ultimately how I would like the desk to function.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I'm sorry, it's the faster one that should have the speed control! I've added the schematic.

Comment: Thanks @vu2nan. Based on the schematic, are the actuators connected to the 4PDT switch? Will the speed controller now be able to relatively sync both actuators?

Comment: Will i also need to buy an additional power supply? The current one that i bought has an output voltage of 6A. The max amp for the actuators are 3amps each. 

I am using a RioRand 12V-40V 10A PWM DC Motor Speed Controller and thinking about buying uxcell AC 15A/250V 10A/380V 12 Screw Terminals On/On 4PDT Toggle Switch on amazon.

All of this knowledge shared is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi Daniel, Both the actuators can be operated with the 4PDT switch. The slower one is run directly from the power supply and the other through the PWM control to reduce its speed to suit. You may try to match them as described earlier. You need to buy an On-Off-On 4PDT switch to stop the actuators with the same switch. I am glad if I could be of some help!

Comment: Thank you, Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to add feedback to each linear actuator.

The red rectangle is the movable portion of the desk.

The green circle is a code disk that is attached to a fixed part of the desk.

The blue line is a string or fishing line that is attached to the movable portion of the desk and is looped around the code disk assembly.

As the desk rises, or lowers, the code disk spins.

The string and pulley on code disk could be replaced by a rack and pinion gear assembly.

[image]

edit: silly me ... all you need is a tilt sensor, not position feedback

Comment: also an elaborate controller and an H-bridge or something to drive the motor with the controller